# Eclipse : change permission file and commit does not work

Tags: eclipse, svn

I just forget to applied permission of the files that I just recently commited, but when afterwards I add permission to those file (chmod 755), eclipse can not detect the changes commit it again (obviously, as the exact content apart from the permission is detected).

I can actualy add some comment on the script, and force eclipse to commit the file, but maybe any other way is available?

Thank you :)

Comment: even with making a change to the file in eclipse and changing the properties, this still still did not work! had to use the answer from @Lithium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that SVN is all that good about picking up file permissions.  The svn book shows how to set permissions on files through the svn commandline however, maybe it will help.

```
svn propset svn:executable ON somescript
svn commit
```

[svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re23.html)